# How to run a 32bit dotnet 6 console application in Ubantu machine

Tags: c#, linux, cross-platform, .net-6.0, 32-bit

currently I have created a .net console App using dotnet new console -n HelloWorld. if I try to build it using dotnet build and run using dotnet run I am able to see the output . and the .csproj of this 64bit App is like this.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But if I try to run this as a 32bit App by adding `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

then if I try to build this application by using `dotnet build` I am able to build but if I try to run by using `dotnet run` it gives me the error as

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 
'/home/simu_linux/Test/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/net6.0/HelloWorld.dll'. An attempt was made
 to load a program with an incorrect format. File name: 
'/home/simu_linux/Test/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/net6.0/HelloWorld.dll'
```

then I tried couple of way to solve this I tried to run directly from bin folder `dotnet <myapp>.dll` this also gave the same error . I tried by using `dotnet run -c Debug -r linux-x86` I got the below error
[image]

I tried with mono I was able to run this 32bit by using `mono <myapp>.dll` but If I keep any System.IO logic.
[image]

and then If use mono `<myapp>.dll` then I facing issue
[image]
I guess I have to use this command

```
dotnet run -c Debug -r linux-x86
```

but since linux-86 RID is not there in my ubantu How can I solve this issue.
since all my libraries are in 32 bit so I need a executable in 32 bit , I can not migrate it to 64 bit. So Can any please tell me how can I generate a custom 32bit dotnet for linux(ubantu).

Comment: What is your actual problem? Why do you need to run this in 32 bit mode?

Comment: Your runtime should be 32bit too, since there's no official 32bit dotnet on Linux, build it by yourself.

Comment: @shingo Not to say that running 32 bit apps on a 64 bit linux often doesn't work out of the box. So if one has the source code for an application, there's rarely a reason to do so.

Comment: @PMF It is still common to manipulate some ancient devices with their closed source and non maintained libraries.

Comment: @shingo Sure, I'm not saying there aren't any use cases for it. But this one - at least from the information we have - clearly is not.

Comment: Hi @PMF . since all my libraries are in 32 bit so I need a executable in 32 bit , I can not migrate it to 64 bit, but we are able to build it by using 'dotnet build' command, why its not running , if you have any idea how to generate a custom build for 32 bit could you please guild me how can I generate that

Comment: It would have been good if you mentioned that in your question. You need to install the 32 bit dotnet runtime and try with that. As noted above, there's no official x86 build for linux available, but you can build it yourself.

Comment: Hi @PMF , I have updated the question as per your suggestion , but do you have any document for , how to create a custom dotnet  32bit build for linux(unabtu)

Comment: I would start by checking out http://github.com/dotnet/runtime and try to build it. Maybe ask a new question if you get stuck. But I would rather consider updating your libraries, as you'll likely have to do that sooner or later anyway. Are these .NET libraries or C++?

Comment: Hi @PMF ,thanks for your response actually some are in c++ and some are in .net standard 2.0.

Comment: Ok, so don't care about those in .netstandard, these are (by definition) platform independent and will run on 64 bit just fine. C++ is more difficult, but as said, sooner or later you'll have to migrate them anyway, as support for 32 bit applications is dropping.