# Use Mono to load and access simple DLL in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono

I am wondering if I am misunderstanding what Mono can do?

I am not a C# or .NET person, so bear with me. What I need is to be able to load an external (third-party) .DLL which was built to be used with .NET project (.NET 4.6 in particular).

The DLL File is: PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows

What I did in the Windows was very simple: I have opened Visual Studio, added reference to the file and that's it, I was able to import it with 'Using Driver.dll;' right away and use it.

Now, I need to do the same on my Ubuntu 22.04 OS. From what I understand, I should be able to do this using Mono. I have installed Mono, successfully ran Hello World application, but now, I am lost at how am I supposed to use Mono to import my DLL file.

I want to remind, I do not need to do anything complicated, I just want to load that DLL and call 1 method, and that is it.

- I have installed Mono, and the Mono 'Compatibility' page says that it supports .NET 4.6, but how does it work exactly. When I run csc HelloWorld.cs, how will it know what to use and where.
- How do I exactly import the DLL? I saw [Dllmaps](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/) page, but it was not helpful for me, as I understand, it maps given DLL files to already existing .so libraries, and I do not have that and I do not know anything about the internals of the .DLL, besides the few methods it contains. I also tried to -r:Driver.dll during build, but I assume that is not it, as I am not able to use it in code:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException:
```

Please, could someone just point me to what should I do, if I want to just import one DLL and use its function in the same way I did very effortlessly in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: I am not staying on Windows, I just need to access the .DLL file on Linux. I just used Windows to test out the .dll, that's it...

Comment: The author(s) of that .NET assembly decided what are the supported platforms. And if it targets .NET Framework, not .NET 6/8, then most likely it was never supposed to be used on Linux. Mono wasn't invented to break the barriers. In 2024, you should ask the original author(s) to give you .NET 6/8 NuGet packages, not hoping for some magic.

Comment: If you read the question, you would find out that it targets .NET 4.6

Comment: Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879759/how-to-run-a-32bit-dotnet-6-console-application-in-ubantu-machine#comment137297453_77879759 I think the solution should be the same, the good news is mono is likely to have a readmade i386 binary. And as metioned above, if you want an experience similar to VS, you can download dotdevelop or monodevelop.

Comment: @shingo I am noob with .NET so I am failing to see how your link relates to my question. The DLL I have is already built and I do not have source code or anything to build it myself, I just need to be able to use the DLL.

Comment: You need an i386 version of mono first. How did you use the DLL on Windows if you don't build anything? rundll32?

Comment: I created new project (console application) in Visual Studio, selected .NET framework 4.6, I just took the DLL file, used 'Add Project Reference', imported the file, and just did in the code 'Using MyDriverNamespace;' and was able to access all the classes and methods.

Comment: And then you write that code of yours, using all those classes and methods you can access, and build that EXE, on your windows machine if you like, and transfer the EXE to the linux box and run it with mono, like `mono my.exe`, and figure out any downstream problems from there. You don't transfer the PE32 DLL to the linux box and run it with mono; that would be like trying to run an entrypoint-less pure library functions DLL on windows. In your comment above you said "I just need to be able to use the DLL" - use it in VS, write code with it, call it, etc, then build and run the result w/ mono

Comment: If Mono cannot emulate the most basic thing that is possible on Windows .NET Visual Studio, what is even the point of using it then?

Comment: Mono isn't visual studio, its function is equivalent to msbuild and clr, and you still need to build an executable in order to use the dll, just like what you have done in Visual Studio.

Comment: ok, the issue is sorted, I have downloaded MonoDevelop and was able to just import my dll and make calls there.